# Github ignore multiple node_modules

Tags: github, gitignore

Im having two kind of node_modules in my folders.
One in the root folder, that works fine, but one also in the folder called "`html/app`" ( so would be `html/app/node_modules` )

Why wont it ignore it? it adds everything in the node_modules app folder when i do the command "`git commit` ".

Current .gitignore contains:

```
/dist
/tmp
/out-tsc

# dependencies
/node_modules
/html/app/node_modules


html/app/node_modules
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right - you want to ignore both node_modules folders.

Try to cut that folder from project, then commit it and then return node_modules folder back.

Future commit's would ignore both folders.

**EDIT:** Probably it works in that way now because of that git already track that folder.

Comment: How can i make sure i untrack it?

Comment: @maria just commit that deletion and than use git status to see current status of your branch

Comment: @maria also to see untracked files use: git ls-files --others --exclude-standard